# how to control robot arm with servos by potentiometer

Tags: raspbian, gpio, python, pi-3, hardware

i bought a robot arm consist of 6 servos, is there a possibility to control the servos with potentiometer as the potentiometer moves the servo moves, i wont be using any HAT.
thanks

Answer (score 2):

Certainly.

Connect the pot wiper line to the input of an ADC (Analogue to Digital Converter).  An MCP3008 would be a reasonable ADC as it has 8 inputs so you could use a pot per servo.

An MCP3008 will return a number between 0 and 1023 for the pot.  0 at one extreme, 1023 at the other.

Connect the MCP3008 to the Pi using SPI.

Map the values you read from the pot to a servo pulsewidth, say 1000 if you read 0, and 2000 if you read 1023.  Send the mapped servo pulsewidth to the servo control line.

The servo will then turn as you turn the pot.

Here is a Python example of using one pot to drive one servo.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

# servo_pot.py
# 2016-07-25
# Public Domain

import time

import pigpio  # http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html

SERVO=14

MIN_SERVO=500
MAX_SERVO=2500

MIN_POT_CAP=0
MAX_POT_CAP=1023

def map(val, in_min, in_max, out_min, out_max):
   return (val - in_min) * (out_max - out_min) / (in_max - in_min) + out_min

pi = pigpio.pi() # Connect to Pi.

if not pi.connected:
   exit()

adc = pi.spi_open(1, 40000, 0) # Open SPI channel 1.

while True:

   try:

      c, d = pi.spi_xfer(adc, [1, 0x80, 0]) # Read channel 0.

      v = ((d[1]<<8) | d[2]) & 0x3FF

      micros = map(v, MIN_POT_CAP, MAX_POT_CAP, MIN_SERVO, MAX_SERVO)

      pi.set_servo_pulsewidth(SERVO, micros)

      time.sleep(0.02)

   except:

      break

print("\nexiting...")

pi.spi_close(adc) # Release SPI handle.

pi.stop() # Disconnect from Pi.
```

Comment: thank you for your help, how can i know each line and syntax means, because im still in the beginning in learning python.
and again your answer was very helpful thank you.

Comment: if you please suggest the best way to learn python coding.

Comment: There is no best way.  What works for one person doesn't work for another.  Search for on-line tutorials until you find one which works for you.

Comment: please excuse me for my low knowledge to python, what if i need to it for 6 servos what shouldi change ?
thank you

Comment: You would have to read 6 channels from the ADC to get the individual pot readings and send the output to the GPIO dedicated to that servo.

Comment: if you please explain for me the while loop because I searched every where and i cant understand it.
thank you..

Comment: You need to find an on-line Python tutorial which works for you.